# Updating State when box is unchecked

Tags: reactjs

I'm running into a little bit of an issue, wrote an app and is working mostly except for the check boxes. They'll add the fee when checked, but if they're unchecked after being checked it doesn't update like I need it to. Does anyone have any recommendations for fixing?

```
  const [laptop, setLaptop] = useState(0);

  const handleCheckBoxFour = (checked) => {
    if (!checked) {
      setLaptop(0);
    } else if (checked) {
      setLaptop(25);
    }
  };

 <span className="leftspace">Laptop</span>
 <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheckBoxFour}></input>
```

Comment: Provide `setLaptop` function

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @kinduser Most likely `setLaptop()` is comes from the `useState()` hook. We definitely need to see this as part of the code example, though.

Comment: Added the setLaptop, it's just simple useState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checked` will always be true on your example, because that's actually the input change event. do something like:

```js
 const handleCheckBoxFour = (e) => {
    if (!e.target.checked) {
      setLaptop(0);
    } else if (e.target.checked) {
      setLaptop(25);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can check:

1. change onChange to onClick
2. change this line {() => handleCheckBoxFour}
3. 'checked' is probably not true or false but an event. Try event.target.value